# error serving JS files

Tags: go

I have this directory structure

```
src/
  github.com/
    john/
      site/
        main.go
        templates/
          index.html
        static/
          js/
            site.js
          css/
```

In my main.go:

```
func main() {
  http.Handle("/templates/", http.StripPrefix("/templates/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(filepath.Join(cwd, "/github.com/john/site/templates/"))))
  http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(filepath.Join(cwd, "/github.com/john/site/static/"))))
```

In index.html

```
<script src="/static/js/site.js"></script>
```

The HTML loads properly. However, no such js file was found. Why is that so?

I run go install within the `src` directory. Also, when I try to access localhost:3000/templates/index.html, the file is not found either.

Comment: I run go install within the src directory. How should I do it then?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: What is `os.Cwd()` showing? (print it to console at the top of main)

Comment: /Users/John/Projects/Website

Comment: given that cwd, there's no way the path is right since you are at least missing "src" and maybe more depending on where your example tree is sitting

Answer (score 0):

js folder is not under static. it should be like

```
static/
      js/
        site.js
```